# Ubuntu 14.04 Server Install Image. Need to get Internet access

Tags: networking

when i was installing Ubuntu 14.04 Server Install Image, i got a DHCP error. I said continue without configuring DHCP. I completed my installation and the server is up and running.

The server is physically connected to the network. Now what should i do to access internet from the server.

I am a beginner. It will be great if someone can take me to the right step by step process to setup the network on the server.

Comment: Do you have a DHCP server running on your network?

Comment: Typically consumer grade routers and wireless access points are running DHCP servers.

Answer (score 0):

This is a server. Use a static IP.

To do this, open up `/etc/network/interfaces` and add this:

```
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.25
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.1.1
```

Of course, set the IPs to the proper values.

`address` --> IP Address you want the server to have
`netmask` --> Your system's NetMask (usually `255.255.255.0`)
`gateway` --> Your router's IP address

Remove this line if it exists:

```
iface eth0 inet dynamic
```

Now, you have IP addresses assigned. You need a DNS server to use hostnames on the Internet. Do this by opening `/etc/resolv.conf` and removing all `nameserver` lines. Then, add these:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Replace above IPs with whatever nameserver/DNS server you want to use.

Finally, reboot (Will almost always work) or run the below command to apply the changes.

```
sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0
```

[(Src)](http://www.howtoforge.com/linux-basics-set-a-static-ip-on-ubuntu)